# How do transformations in embedding space specify transformations of fields on sections?

Tags: field-theory, conformal-field-theory, geometry

This question is from Slava Rychkov's EPFL Lectures on Conformal Field Theory
in D >= 3 Dimensions.

The conformal group in $D$ dimensions is isomorphic to $SO(D+1,1)$ where the action is linear: $X \rightarrow \Lambda X$. The action leaves the null cone $X^2 = 0$ invariant and we take a section of the null cone $X = (1, x^2, x^\mu)$ to serve as the space on which the CFT is defined. We can calculate the induced metric on this section as well as the transformation of the induced metric under a position-dependent scale transformation:

$$X \rightarrow \lambda(X) X \quad \implies ds'^2 = c(x) ds^2 \quad \mathrm{where} \quad c(x) = \lambda(X)^2. \qquad (2.19)$$

This much I understand. Now let us stipulate that a field defined in the $(D+1,1)$-dimensional embedding space satisfies $\phi(\lambda X) = \lambda^\Delta \phi(X)$. How is it that we conclude from all this that the field restricted to the aforementioned section satisfies $\phi (x') = c(x)^{-\Delta} \phi(x)$?

Slava says that "Indeed, c(x) in this equation is the local expansion factor, and according to Eq. (2.19) it must be identfied with λ(X), the scale factor in the second phase of SO(D+ 1,1) action." But I do not understand how we are obtaining an equation for $\phi$ from (2.19) where $\phi$ does not appear at all. What is the relationship between $\phi$ and the induced metric that I am missing?